# Issue with registering EC2 instance with ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm new to AWS and have been trying to register an EC2 instance into an ECS cluster.

The purpose is to resolve the error "ECS Fargate does not support bind mounts from host: incompatible attribute" when deploying with "docker compose up".

I'm following this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html . However, I only can create running ec2 instance and it is not registered with the ecs cluster.

I do have IAM role with `ecsInstanceRole` and also configure user data with:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=your_cluster_name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

Have anyone had this issue before and what should I do to resolve this?
You help would be much appreciated as I have been stuck in this issue for a while now.

Comment: Does your EC2 instance have internet access or access to ECS through an interface endpoint?

Comment: Hi @Marcin do you mean Auto-assign Public IP is enabled or disabled? Currently mine is disabled

Comment: I mean, your EC2 instance must be able to connect to ECS service. So have you ensured such connectivity?

Comment: ah right @Marcin .Yes I do have an interface endpoint and currently the VPC is connected to my ECS VPC (if that makes sense. Sorry I'm new so the way I explain might not clear). And based on that, I guess there is internet connection to ECS through that endpoint. But I haven't seen one before, this is my practice task so I'm not sure if it's correct

Comment: Its difficult to provide you any help, as you are not provide any details of your setup. Security groups, VPC setup, etc....

Comment: oh sorry @Marcin, here are some details, please let me know if you need further info:
- Security group: ecsInstanceRole 
- Security group name: sg-031306bd4d4c625b7 - Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux 2 AMI-2.0.20220411-AutogenByAWSMP--2
- Set up for VPC:
IPv4 CIDR: 10.0.0.0/16
DHCP options set: dopt-c2b1aca5
Main route table: rtb-0021d1ec0b4b9da01
Main network ACL: acl-0356c5da88f982ee6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244182/discussion-between-catopus-and-marcin).